# DDD and Persistence. Again

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design, persistence

I am struggling with persistence in Domain Driven Design. As far as I understand, domain model should never be persistent-aware. Let's say I am building a simple todo-list application. I have a task with following interface:

```
interface ITask
{
   bool IsCompleted {get;}
   string Description {get;}

   void Complete();
   void ChangeDescription(string description);
}
```

And the generic implementation should look like this:

```
class SimpleTask : ITask
{
    public SimpleTask(string description)
    {
       ChangeDescription(description);
    }

    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public void Complete()
    {
       IsCompleted = true;
    }

    public void ChangeDescription(string description)
    {
       // some validation here
       // ...
       Description = description;
    }
}
```

I want to have a description be necessary - because it's a business rule. So from this moment if I want to save this object via serializers I will fail because no parameterless constructor provided. And I shouldn't provide it because of no persistance-aware rule. If I model my task in a form of DTO\POCO I will end up with another problem - so called anemic model. Moreover, I don't want to provide setters to some properties.

So where is the solution to all of this? I can create a tightly-coupled saver that will know how to save and restore task state. But I can access only public properties and methods, what if internal logic of task will be complex and impossible to save\restore? Should I mark all fields in task internal and have a possibility to save inner state of object? Isn't it kinda code smell and violation of no persistence-aware rule?

How do you solve this?

Comment: Have a look at the following link which discusses validation in DDD: http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/05/19/validation-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my understanding, Entity Framework is much less flexible than Hibernate so you will have to make a bit more compromises in the model. Vaughn Vernon, the author of Implementing Domain-Driven Design (IDDD) [shows a great way](https://kalele.io/the-ideal-domain-driven-design-aggregate-store/) of keeping self-encapsulated entities while making it easy to persist their state using Entity Framework.

If you can use the persistence store of your choice, you may as well use a different strategy that doesn't involve so much impedance mismatch (e.g. event sourcing).

Comment: Link dead? Any new ideas on this topic 8 years later?

Comment: @swcloud Fixed the first link but could not find the other one. I don't use .NET so I don't know much about EF, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the sample project from the author of DDD (http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/), you can see that Entities have a private empty-parameters constructor as a workaround for the Hibernate requirement for an object to be persisted.
So, a level of "dirtiness" in model's objects, I think, is allowed when it's due to technical limitations of the language or infrastructure.
Anyway, I'd suggest you to expose the creation of a ToDo entity via some factory methods (maybe of an Aggregate Root), so that you can enforce your business rule for object creation. That way, you give the client a sort of **convention** for operating with your model in the proper way.
You cannot avoid clients to create an invalid state model (think about reflection, byte code instrumentation, etc.), so what is really important is to design the proper way to use your model and instruct the client about it.

Comment: So if the factory will be a start point for model creation, what will be the end of this? I mean, where the saving will rise?

Comment: The Repository is the Domain Service that has the responsibility to persist Aggregate Roots. Clients of the domain model will use it to retrieve and persist  ARs. Repositories KNOW the ARs and related Entitites they manage, while Entities don't know about Repositories.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the state of already-persisted entities should not go through the same invariant enforcement upon rehydration as if it were a fresh new state you're trying to reach. Otherwise when your invariant code changes, the entities in your database may not be valid any more and you might lose a lot of history if you don't take compensating actions (filling in default values, etc.)

Concretely, this means :

- Your ORM can perfectly have direct access to the entity's state via a parameterless constructor (how could it know what to pass to a constructor with params anyway ?) and setters. While it has an impact on your entities indeed, you can minimize it, for instance making the constructor protected and the setters private which is [possible in Entity Framework](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/04/29/domain-modeling-with-entity-framework-scorecard/), and I wouldn't call that "persistence awareness" per se.

Or,

- You have to detach persisted state from your main Entity object. See plalx's and Adrian's answers for classic approaches.

[Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) solves this in an elegant way. The notion of state reconstitution is ingrained in the entity itself because it knows what to do with the various events coming at it. Still it is not considered persistence awareness -- events are *replayed* when rehydrating an entity, but this triggers the very same logic as the first time they are *played* against the entity.

Comment: Never used ES just yet, but I do you know if event stores are doing a binary serialization of the event or they serialize in JSON or something else? If using binary serialization, how do you deal with event class changes?

Comment: You can replace the event stream using upgraders without caring much about its internal representation : https://abdullin.com/post/event-sourcing-versioning/

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use a onion/hexagon/ports & adapters style architecture, with my domain consisting of an application layer that references a domain model layer.  I usually end up with most of my domain specific persistence in the application layer.  I do most of my persistence layer operations from the application layer.  My classes and methods in the application layer are named after business functions, processes and workflows, and they handle the fetching and saving of entities.

To answer the main part of your question, I find using an ORM (particularly code-first) very difficult with DDD.  Domain entities in something like Entity Framework are very different to entities in DDD, they just share the same word.  There are proponents of the DDD and EF world who will advocate drawn out procedures to get these 2 things working together.  Personally, the so-called ORM benefits of lazy loading and navigation properties are reason enough for me to keep my ORM hidden behind my repositories.  I.e. the repositories accept and return domain entities, what goes on in the repository method is usually some mapping to and from ORM generated entities.  For this reason, I tend to go for the DB generated entities rather than code first, just because I'm not getting the so-called goodness from my ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is always going to be some persistence related behaviour in your domain.  You just have to decide how much :)

I don't like ORMs and some require too much messing about with the domain classes such as marking methods virtual or, horror of horrors, attributes.

Your domain object has **behaviour** and it has **shape**.  You want to retrieve the shape part (state) and persist *that*.  When loading your object you want to give that state back to the object to "hydrate".  This is the momento pattern.

Event Sourcing (ES) is really along those lines too.  An event represents some state change in the object.  Loading the event back changes the state internally to be consistent.

In ES a *Snapshot* is used to improve performance when there are really many events.  The *Snapshot* represents the state at a particular point in time and all events after that point in time are also applied.  The *Snapshot* is also following the momento pattern.

So it boils down to ***how*** you want to expose your object's state.